# Access and update value in hash of hashes Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this massive nested Ruby hash:

```
hash_filter = {
  "m-ct-filter-bot"=>{
    "parameters"=>{
      "filter_action"=>"keep", "filter_key"=>"classification.identifier",
      "filter_regex"=>nil, "filter_value"=>""
    },
    "group"=>"Expert", "name"=>"Filter", "module"=>"bots.experts.filter.expert",
    "description"=>"modified by mf370"
  },
  "m-vision-filter-bot"=>{
    "parameters"=>{
      "filter_action"=>"keep", "filter_key"=>"classification.identifier",
      "filter_regex"=>nil, "filter_value"=>""
    },
    "group"=>"Expert", "name"=>"Filter", "module"=>"bots.experts.filter.expert",
    "description"=>"modified by mf370"
  },
  "m-tele-filter-bot"=>{
    "parameters"=>{
      "filter_action"=>"keep", "filter_key"=>"classification.identifier",
      "filter_regex"=>nil, "filter_value"=>""
    },
    "group"=>"Expert", "name"=>"Filter", "module"=>"bots.experts.filter.expert",
    "description"=>"modified by mf370"
  }
}
```

And this array:

```
array_id = ["ct","vision","tele"]
```

I'm trying to update the value on the key `"filter_value"` on each nested hash with the values of the `array_id`. In order to have `filter_value => ct`, `filter_value => vision`, `filter_value => tele` on the corresponding hash.

I have the following code:

```
array_id.each do |id|
  hash_filter.each_pair do |key, value|
    value["parameters"]["filter_value"] = id
    end
  end
```

However, when I run this code the key `filter_value` is updated ALWAYS with the last value of the `array_id`, which means that all my hashes will have the same value `filter_value => tele`.

I'm not getting any errors, is just the output is not what I was expecting.
Can you guys help me out? :)

Thank you!!

Comment: In future, please pare your examples down to the minimum required to make your point. Here the question would have been clearer had your example hash been, for example, `filter = { ct: { a: { b: "keep", value: "" }, c: "Exp" }, vision: { a: { b: "keep", value: "" }, c: "Exp" }, tele: { a: { b: "keep", value: "" }, c: "Exp" } }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happens cause you iterate `array_id` so your hash-value always be the same as last element of this array. There are to many variant to solve this. But next time, you should be more attentive ;)
Thanks to @CarySwoveland:

```
a_id = array_id.dup
hash_filter.each do |_key, value|
   value["parameters"]["filter_value"] = a_id.shift
end
hash_filter
```

Also, for Ruby v2.4.0 you can use new method: [`#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)

```
hash_filter.transform_values.with_index do |value, ind|
   value["parameters"]["filter_value"] = array_id[ind]
end
hash_filter
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! :D

Comment: You don't need indices if you write `a_id = array_id.dup; hash_filter.each { |_key, value| value["parameters"]["filter_value"] = a_id.shift }; hash_filter`. I added `hash_filter` at the end to emphasize that your code does not return the updated `hash_filter`. Also, your method #1 mutates `hash_filter`, whereas [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) does not, which may be a little confusing. ([Hash#transform_values!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values-21) does mutate `hash_filter`).